# How can I show datas not in table with out compairing with other tables in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle-sqldeveloper, backend, plsqldeveloper

I have one table named FILEINFO. Daily some file_names(around 100) will come. I need to check whether the names are present in the table or not. in a single query

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Oracle?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this fits in with your data pipeline, but one clean approach here would be to write those new incoming file names into some sort of table (temporary or permanent), and then use a simple exists query to check if they are already present in your current table, e.g.

```
SELECT filename AS new_file
FROM temp_names t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM FILEINFO t2 WHERE t2.filename = t1.filename);
```

If you wanted to insert only new file names, you could use similar logic, e.g.

```
INSERT INTO FILEINFO (filename)
SELECT filename
FROM temp_names t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM FILEINFO t2 WHERE t2.filename = t1.filename);
```

Comment: I would like to do it with a temporary table. (Using UNPIVOT and DUAL)

Comment: @LibinMathew This is about as specific an answer I can give you, given the very limited information in your question.

Answer (score 1):

The other approach would be without using a temporary table (Tim Biegeleisen answer). 
This approach will only use one query

```
SELECT 
  FILEINFO.filename
FROM (
  SELECT 'filename1' AS filename FROM DUAL
  UNION
  SELECT 'filename2' AS filename FROM DUAL
) AS file_names 
LEFT JOIN 
 FILEINFO 
ON
 file_names.filename = FILEINFO.filename
WHERE 
 FILEINFO.filename IS NULL
```

This query should also work in both MySQL and Oracle database. 
Both database systems are using `DUAL` as a "dummy" table to allow tableless SELECTS

Comment: I have a large amount of data so i can't go with unions..  I need to use UNPIVOT  in DUAL and find out the data's not in the table.

Comment: "I have a large amount of data so i can't go with unions.. I need to use UNPIVOT in DUAL and find out the data's not in the table. " @LibinMathew in that case for better answer(s) see [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)